# Overloaded function print

Tags: c++, arrays, printing

For one of the assignments I need to create an overloaded function ***print*** that prints an element or all elements of an array. I have no problem with printing the entire array:

```
for( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << list [ i ] <<endl;
```

But how do I make the same function to print only one particular element?
The way I see it is to ask a user what to print, either one element or all numbers. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I assume you're using C++? If so, add it to the tags of your question.

Comment: Never understood that spaced-out ` \[ \]` convention

Comment: Is the array fixed size, or dynamically allocated?

Answer (score 1):

Printing  entire array

```
print (const int *arr) const
{
   // code you have written
}
```

Printing particular array element

```
print (const int *arr, const int index)const // overloaded function
{
  // validate index and print arr[index]
   if (index >=0 && index<size)
       cout << *(arr+index)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Since you're talking about overloading, I assume you're using C++.)

A function that overloads another is not the same function anymore. In your case, you would need one function that prints one element. In other words, just one `int`:

```
void print(int num)
{ cout << num << endl; }
```

You then provide an overload that takes a range and prints it:

(Note that in a range, the `end` element refers to "one past the end of the range" and should not be printed.)

```
void print(int* begin, int* end)
{
    while (begin != end) {
        cout << *begin << endl;
        // Or if you want to follow correct decomposition design:
        // print(*begin);
        ++begin;
    }
}
```

Usage of the two functions:

```
int array[3] = {1, 2, 3};
print(array[0]);
print(array, array + 3);
```

Comment: Does C not have function overloading?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nope.